# How to display User with cookie? asp.net

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I have the following cookie in my login page:

```
       Response.Cookies("userInfo")("userName") = "s"
       Response.Cookies("userInfo")("lastVisit") = DateTime.Now.ToString()
       Response.Cookies("userInfo").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
       Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
```

and this on my default.aspx:

```
       If Not Request.Cookies("userName") Is Nothing Then
           Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("userName").Value)
       End If

       If Not Request.Cookies("userName") Is Nothing Then
           Dim aCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("userName")
           Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value)
       End If
```

but I need to have: `Response.Cookies("userInfo")("userName") = "s"` to be the value of : textboxUser. How can this be done?

I tried : `Response.Cookies("userInfo")("userName") = "textboxUser.Text"`

But then it just displays that, not the user.

Also, when I fill in : `Response.Cookies("userInfo")("userName") = "s"` It doesnt display "s" on the default page but : `Label`

Can someone point me in a good direction?

Comment: Have you actually wrapped "textboxUser.Text" in quotes? If so, try removing the quotes.

Comment: Ah good one! but it still display Label on the default.aspx. What is wrong with that code? when i do: userInfo instead of userName I get the following: `userName=Tester&lastVisit=7-5-2013 16:48:04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're only setting a cookie called `userInfo`, inside which is an item called `userName`. You should be checking for the existence of the `userInfo` cookie then get the items within it, e.g.

```
Dim aCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("userInfo")

If aCookie IsNot Nothing Then
    Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie("userName"))
End If
```

Also, where you're just displaying this cookie's `.Value`, it will return all keys and their values within the cookie, a bit like a query string.